# Dynamic model with Array object in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I am saving my data in below format

```
$scope.data = {
   name:'abc',
   Address:[{
     Address1:'XXXX',
     state:'XXXX',
     County:'XXXX'
   }]
}


<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Address1" ng-model="data.Address[0][Address1]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" ng-model="data.Address[1][State]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="County" ng-model="data.Address[2][County]">
```

While retrieving the data I am getting data in below format:

```
$scope.data = {
   name:'abc',
   Address:[{
     state:'XXXX',
     County:'XXXX'
   }]
}
```

Where one of the array objects (`Address1`) is missing so I am unable to update the form model even if the data is available. Is there any workaround to solve the above issue?

Comment: is `data.Address[1]` and `data.Address[2]` a typo in your `state` and `county` input bindings?

Comment: no i want the `state` and `county` to be part of  `data.Address array`

Comment: retrieve  means http response??

Comment: yes from http response @JEMI

Comment: are u getting the expected json format from the server?? can u pls post the json also

Answer (score 0):

Change your input model to index `0`, because that's the array item you are targeting. After that change your reference to the `.` notation and not using brackets `[]`. You can use the brackets, but make sure to make them strings, like `data.Address[0]['Address1']`. But it's not necessary here. Also:

```
<input type="text" name="Address1" ng-model="data.Address[0].Address1">
<input type="text" name="state" ng-model="data.Address[0].state">
<input type="text" name="County" ng-model="data.Address[0].County">
```

*(removed class for simplicity)*

*(are you using `state` or `State`?)*

Comment: i am using `State`, i tried  with both `data.Address[0]['Address1']` and `data.Address[0].Address1` the output i am getting is `Addresses:{0: {Address1: "XXXX",State: "XXXX", County: "XXXX}}`
but the required format is 
`Addresses:[{Address1: "XXXX",State: "XXXX", County: "XXXX}]`